# how to handle docker-compose with dotnetcore console apps

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose, console-application, dockerfile

[image: My project]

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: rss-network

services:     
  message.api:
    image: message.api 
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.message
    container_name: message.api
    environment:
      - "RabbitMq/Host=rabbit"
      - "RabbitMq/Username=guest"
      - "RabbitMq/Password=guest"
      - "chatId=@chat"
      - "token=apitoken"
    links:
      - rabbit

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.2-management
    hostname: rabbit
    container_name: rabbit
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5671:5671"
      - "15671:15671"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "4369:4369"

  tracker:
    image: tracker/ 
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.tracker
    container_name: tracker
    environment:
      - "RabbitMq/Host=rabbit"
      - "RabbitMq/Username=guest"
      - "RabbitMq/Password=guest"
    links:
      - rabbit
      - message.api

  feeding:
    image: feeding_rss/ 
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.feeding_rss
    container_name: feeding_rss
    environment:
      - "RabbitMq/Host=rabbit"
      - "RabbitMq/Username=guest"
      - "RabbitMq/Password=guest"
      - "chatId=@chat"
      - "token=apitoken"
    links:
      - rabbit
      - message.api
```

my dockerfiles look like :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-sdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.sln ./
COPY ./business_logic/*.csproj ./business_logic/
COPY ./data_access/*.csproj ./data_access/
COPY ./message/*.csproj ./message/
COPY ./tracker/*.csproj ./tracker/
COPY ./feeding_rss/*.csproj ./feeding_rss/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/<project-name>.dll"]
```

firstly I got

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on
>   this host?

and I use this command `eval $(docker-machine env default)` error is gone.
Now I'm getting this error after docker-compose build :

```
rabbit uses an image, skipping
Building message.api Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
   File "compose\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
   File "compose\cli\main.py", line 118, in perform_command
   File "compose\cli\main.py", line 239, in build
   File "compose\project.py", line 314, in build
   File "compose\service.py", line 888, in build
   File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 207, in build
   File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 254, in _set_auth_headers
   File "site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 85, in resolve_authconfig
   File "site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 129, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('docker-credential-wincred not installed or not available in PATH',) Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I got this error.

Comment: what windows do you have and have set the docker settings? (you can go to Settings -> Shared Drivers -> Reset crerdentials .. and reset your credentials once to be safe that's not the problem)

Comment: i have windows 10.I'm using kitematic and virtualbox vm

Comment: If I am not mistakend the docker toolbox is legacy and you should use the docker for windows (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows)

Comment: I'm trying your solution

Comment: @Edwin your solution didn't work. error is same

Comment: `'docker-credential-wincred not installed or not available in PATH` you have a credential problem with your windows, did you added the credentials in the docker settings?